# Recurrent nerural network predicting the same answer

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to predict if a stock price is going to go up or down the next day. I am using a pandas DataFrame that has 43 columns of which one is the y value, the y values are floats between 0 and 1, also my DataFrame has 5016 rows indexed with numbers. I made a model with some LSTM cells some Dense cells with the loss function being biary_crossentropy, but when I run the model and try to print the predictions all of the predictions are the same:

> [[0.56393844]

> [0.56393844]

> [0.56393844]

> ...

> [0.56393844]

> [0.56393844]

> [0.56393844]]

The y values are not all the same. Y values:

> 0

> 1

> 0

> 1

> 1

The loss and accuracy also start being the same:

> Epoch 7/10

> 4012/4012 [==============================] - 20s 5ms/sample - loss: 0.7052 - acc: 0.5015 - val_loss:

> 0.6884 - val_acc: 0.5488

> Epoch 8/10

> 4012/4012 [==============================] - 19s 5ms/sample - loss: 0.7054 - acc: 0.4980 - val_loss:

> 0.6907 - val_acc: 0.5488

> Epoch 9/10

> 4012/4012 [==============================] - 18s 5ms/sample - loss: 0.7078 - acc: 0.4890 - val_loss:

> 0.6894 - val_acc: 0.5488

My code looks like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("^AEX.csv")
df.index = pd.to_numeric(df.index, errors = 'coerce')
df = df.drop(['date'], axis = 1)
print(df.shape)
x = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'result']
y = df.loc[:, df.columns == 'result']

y = y.astype(int)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle = False)
x_train = x_train.values.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1])
x_test = x_test.values.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, x_test.shape[1])

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(42, input_shape = (1, 42), activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(42, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.1, decay=1e-7)

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 1, validation_data = (x_test, y_test))

prediction = model.predict(x_test)
print(prediction)
print(x_test)
print(y_test)
```

I don't know much about neural networks, so I don't know which layers are the most effective or how many layers I should make. If somebody knows how I can fix this so my neural network actually learns, please let me know. I you know how to make my network more efficient or better also let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use "binary_crossentropy" that means your answer will either be rounded to 0 or 1. Most likely, your LSTM found that if it predicts 1s all the time, it will get an overall score above 50%, which is better than 50/50 guessing. This is a very common problem in ML in binary problems. The reason you get 0.56 is because you use "accuracy" as metric which is correct/all guesses, and if you predict that all are 1s every time, you will get the same accuracy.

The problem lies in your model, that might either be too simple, too complex, or have the wrong tuning values. Try removing one LSTM layer, experiment with their node sizes etc until you get a non-uniform answer.

Comment: When I remove my LSTM layer it still gives me the same answer, even if i make some very weird architectures whatever I do it eventually becomes all the same. Could you please give me some examples of what I should do. Like adding layers, changing hyper parameters etc.

Comment: Learning rate seems very high, try decrease it. Try with/without dropout, very high/low num of nodes etc. Since you are predicting stocks and it is a very hard task, especially with so little data, it is very hard to find patterns, therefore it would make sense if always predicting the most common y will be the ML:s best guess. I would probably try increase node size to try to find more abstract patterns, but most likely you will get the same results.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please tell me what you mean by node size and if you think changing the model, metrics, optimizer, loss, epochs, batch_size will also help.

Comment: You need great intuition for what works in ML to know what to tune for your specific problem, I would suggest starting with simpler problems where you can actually predict something reliably before getting into finance. Since the stocks are already determined by extremely clever ML algorithms your simple LSTM will not be able to find those very hard to find patters, especially not without proper preprocessing and feature engineering. I have not predicted finance and I dont know about your training dataset, therefore I cannot be more specific about what to tune :)

Comment: My Dataset is combines 42 of the most used tech indicators with different periods, I wanted to use LSTM because LSTM should know what information to use, which to forget .etc. Also if you know I can make it so that the model takes in the data of the last N days, oposed to only one day.